# compare client certificates in go

Tags: go, x509certificate

My use case looks like I know the public certificates of my clients and only want to allow them. I have a go server based on gin and a TLS configuration in which I have assigned a method to the property "VerifyPeerCertificate".
The function looks like

```
func customVerifyPeerCertificate(rawCerts [][]byte, verifiedChains [][]*x509.Certificate) error {

if len(verifiedChains) < 1 {
    return errors.New("Verified certificate chains is empty.")
}
if len(verifiedChains[0]) < 1 {
    return errors.New("No certificates in certificate chains.")
}
if len(verifiedChains[0][0].Subject.CommonName) < 1 {
    return errors.New("Common name can not be empty.")
}

fmt.Println(verifiedChains[0][0].Raw)

publicKeyDer, _ := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(verifiedChains[0][0].PublicKey)

publicKeyBlock := pem.Block{
    Type:  "CERTIFICATE",
    Bytes: publicKeyDer,
}
publicKeyPem := string(pem.EncodeToMemory(&publicKeyBlock))
}
```

The problem is, however, that the string in the variable "publicKeyPem" does not look like the client public certificate I used to send the request to the server, it's also shorter in length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A certificate is more than its public key. The entire [x509.Certificate](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#Certificate) object represents the certificate presented by the client, the public key field is only the actual value of the public key.

If you want to compare certificates for strict equality, you should use the `rawCerts [][]byte` argument passed to your callback. This is mentioned in the [tls.Config](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config) comments for `VerifyPeerCertificate`:

```
    VerifyPeerCertificate, if not nil, is called after normal
    certificate verification by either a TLS client or server. It
    receives the raw ASN.1 certificates provided by the peer and also
    any verified chains that normal processing found. If it returns a
    non-nil error, the handshake is aborted and that error results.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marc, I know that I used the wrong variable. To convert the certificate as a string, as used by the client, use the following code

```
publicKeyBlock := pem.Block{
  Type:  "CERTIFICATE",
  Bytes: rawCerts[0],
}
publicKeyPem := string(pem.EncodeToMemory(&publicKeyBlock))
```